# JAX RS get list of objects

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

Trying to play with JAX RS i want to implement CRUD operations with my data. First of all i want to get list of objects in json formate.

```
@Path("/users")
public class ListUsersRestController {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<User> getUsers(){

        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("Dean", "Winchester"));
        users.add(new User("Sam", "Winchester"));
        users.add(new User("Bobby", "Singer"));
        return users;
    }

    @XmlRootElement
    public class User {

        @XmlElement(name="first-name")
        private String firstName;

        @XmlElement(name="last-name")
        private String lastName;

        public User(){

        }

        public User(String firstName, String lastName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

    }
}
```

When i request my URI i always get 500 server error and there are no any errors in log file (I am using glassfish).

Comment: You need a JSON mapper.

Comment: i thought that JAX RS would automatically convert java objects to json formate, according to this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079195/how-to-get-json-representation-of-java-objects-in-jax-rs-layer-in-java-ee-7 I also tried to return Response instead of list of objects as i mentioned in my question, but i got the same result

Comment: Just for future reference, while typing up your question, you can highlight the entire code block and hit the `{}` button in the editor. This will indent the entire code block, instead of just manually indenting the first line, which messes up your code formatting. I fixed it for you this time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
    ...
}
```

Your `User` class now is an inner class of `ListUsersRestController` and it seems that JAXB fails to marshall inner classes (because they are more like an instance member of `ListUsersRestController` than a real class). Either externalize it to be a normal class or make it `static`:

```
@XmlRootElement
public static class User {
    ...
}
```